# On sums and identities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, self-learning, riemann-sum

I am given the following problem set:

> (a) the Riemann $\zeta$-function for $s > 1$ is defined through the convergent sum: $$\zeta(s) := \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$$
>   show the identity $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} = \frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)$$
>
> (b) show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}= \frac{1}{4}$$
>
> (c) we denote $f_n$ as the $n^{th}$ fibonacci term. Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f_n f_{n+2}} = 1$$

I basically need help on every of those identities since my knowledge about sums is pretty basic. thank you for your hints and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first identity you are interested in the infinite sum of just the odd integers, where $s = 2$. One way you can get this is to observe that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^2} \\ =\zeta(2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4n^2} \\ = \zeta(2)-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \\ = \zeta(2)-\frac{1}{4}\zeta(2)$$ As for part $(b)$, manipulate the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)} \\ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2(n+2)} \\ =\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}\right)- \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)+ \left(\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\right) $$ For part $(c)$ remember that $f_{n+2} = f_{n+1}+f_n$

Comment: I have trouble understanding the first step $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^2}$$ how do we know/get that equality ?

Comment: Do you agree that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$$ is a sum involving only the odd integers?

Comment: ah sure, now I see it! thanks

Comment: Did you get part (b) yet?

Comment: yes i got the equality but i dont see how you continue from there on.

Comment: Does the next hint help?

Comment: unfortunately i can still not see how this all should sum up to $\frac{1}{4}$ ( i have the feeling that these sums together are $0$ hence we would have $\frac{1}{4}$. At least i understand your steps. thank you alot for your help!

Comment: Drop the parentheses at the end of my hint for (b) and combine like terms ;)

Comment: I completed (a) and (b) now I am struggling with (c) so far I have: $$ \frac{1}{f_n f_{n+1}} = \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n f_{n+1}f_{n+1}} = \frac{f_{n+2} - f_n}{f_n f_{n+1}f_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{f_n f_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{f_{n+1}f_{n+2}} $$ $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f_n f_{n+2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{f_n f_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{f_{n+1}f_{n+2}} \right)$$ but how do I continue from here?

Comment: So you rewrote it as another telescoping sum. That is very useful. Just manipulate the sum into a form where it's clear that everything will cancel out. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{f_nf_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{f_{n+1}f_{n+2}}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{f_nf_{n+1}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{f_{n+1}f_{n+2}} \\ = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{f_{n+1}f_{n+2}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{f_{n+1}f_{n+2}}$$

Comment: ah I see just because the first two elements are $1$ in the fibonacci sequence! thank you that was very enlightening!

Comment: Technically the first two elements of the fibonacci sequence are $f_0=0,f_1=1$ but luckily we only care about $f_1=1$ and $f_2=1$ ;) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$. Split the infinite series into two subseries, depending on the parity of each term's denominator.

$(b)$. It's a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

$(c)$. Use the general formula for the $n^{th}$ [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio).

Comment: for (a) who do you mean with parity of the denominator?

Comment: Depending on whether the denominator $n^s$ is either even or odd.